# Serving files using net/http FileServer results in 404

Tags: http, go

I am making a small self-contained service in Go. The UI requires a few JS libraries, so I figured, I would use `http.FileServer` to serve the JS files from node_modules

```
router := chi.NewRouter()
router.Use(middleware.RequestID)
router.Use(middleware.RealIP)
router.Use(middleware.Logger)
router.Use(middleware.Recoverer)
router.Use(middleware.Timeout(60 * time.Second))

router.Get("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "index.html")
})
router.Get("/node_modules/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.StripPrefix("/node_modules/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("node_modules")))
})
... more routes added here for the API ...

listen = ":8080"
log.Infof("listening on %s", listen)
http.ListenAndServe(listen, router)
```

When I try to do

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

In my UI though, I get a 404. The node_modules directory is there and the file exists. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You use both absolute /routed file paths and relative to current working directory. Most likely it cause an error. Check your directory structure and path where you start your server.

Comment: I start the server where the node_modules directory is located. So it should have no trouble finding it. Both of the paths I use are relative, the index.html gets served just fine, but node_modules content does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The pattern was missing a wildcard "/node_modules/*" works. Also, for some reason wrapping a Handler in a HandlerFunc didn't work (returned 000 status and no content). So the resulting route looks like this

```
router.Handle(
    "/node_modules/*",
    http.StripPrefix("/node_modules/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("node_modules"))),
)
```